# Как проверить устойчивость своего сайта к взлому без помощи специалистов ?

Tags: веб-программирование, тестирование

Как проверить устойчивость своего сайта к взлому без помощи специалистов ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо обладать знаниями тех самых специалистов, либо пользоваться теми утилитами, что можно найти в сети. В частности, для сканирования на SQL- и XSS инъекции можно использовать:

- Firefox AddOn [SQL Inject Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/sql-inject-me/)
- [WebCruiser](http://sec4app.com/download-webcruiser) ([описание на русском](https://hpc.name/thread/17443/p1.html))
- [NetSparker](https://www.netsparker.com/communityedition/#prettyphoto[CE]/0/)

и множество [других](http://forum.antichat.net/threadnav240692-1-10.html) [подобных](http://rochakchauhan.com/blog/2008/01/10/top-15-free-sql-injection-scanners/) [утилит](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685884/how-can-i-automatically-test-my-site-for-sql-injection-attacks-using-either-a-s)

Но SQL или XSS инъекции - лишь малая часть способов взламывания сайтов.